# catching an exception in std:sort

Tags: c++, exception

I would like to ask, how to catch an exception, which is thrown somewhere in function `std:sort`. I've tried this code

```
try
{
   sort([arguments])
}
catch(...)
{
   cout << "error";
}
```

However, it does not work. Is there any possibility, how to write this?

Comment: How does it not work?  What happens?  Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: just out of curiosity, what's the exception?

Comment: If you see the exception's type when it's thrown in your debugger, try catching it by name

Comment: I don't see the exception type, as I'm not running the application in debug mode. The best I can do is this : `Unhandled exception at 0x0040627E in graph.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00F5F318.` I can't even provide a minimal example, because this is a part of a quite large project, which throws exception only in very specific case.

Comment: That isn't a C++ exception, but an operating system one. Your program read memory that didn't belong to it.

Comment: Exactly, and I found out, it happened in the sort function. Now I would like to find out, what kind of exception it throws

Comment: @E.Brown it is not an exception. Your program is doing something completely illegal and OS is terminating it. Your code is likely to have a buffer overflow, invalid pointers of something similar somewhere either related to iterators you pass to sort, or comparison function.

Answer (score 4):

Per the comment, re: "Access violation" -- this is an OS-reported exception, not a C++ exception. This is usually the result of passing a comparison object that doesn't create a strict weak ordering. Since you didn't bother to show the "[arguments]" it's not possible to diagnose this any further.

Answer (score 0):

[The reasons that `sort` will throw](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/#exceptions) are:

> - The element comparisons throw
> - The element swaps (or moves) throw
> - The operations on iterators throw

So to cause `sort` to throw without invalid arguments (which would cause undefined behavior) you'll either have to be using a custom iterator or a custom comparator.

Since it's a lot easier to write a conmarator, I'll show you that way:

```
try {
    sort(begin(foo), end(foo), [](auto& lhs, auto& rhs) {
        throw exception();
        return lhs < rhs;
    });
} catch(...) {
    cout << "error\n";
}
```